# Kendo Grid Not Resizing On Mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-mobile

I'm using Kendo Grid on one of my apps with Bootstrap. Except for the Kendo Grid, everything else resizes automatically. I have tried .Mobile(), .Resizable(), .Scrollable() but no luck (see image). What could I do to make the grid resize automatically?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<History>()
      .Name("History")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(c => c.ID).Hidden();
          columns.Bound(c => c.Customer).Title("Client");
          columns.Bound(c => c.ReturnType).Title("Return Type");
          columns.Bound(c => c.Queue).Title("Queue");
          columns.Bound(c => c.NotifyType).Title("Notify Type");
          columns.Bound(c => c.MobilePhone).Title("Mobile Phone");
          columns.Bound(c => c.PreparerName).Title("Prepared By");
          columns.Bound(c => c.AssignedDt).Title("Assigned Time");
          columns.Bound(c => c.IsNoShow).Title("No Show");
          columns.Bound(c => c.IntakeCompletedBy).Title("Intake");
      })
      .Sortable()
      .Mobile(MobileMode.Auto)
      .Resizable(r=>  r.Columns(true))
      .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
      .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
      .Pageable(pageable => pageable
          .Refresh(true)
          .PageSizes(true)
          .ButtonCount(5))
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .Sort(sort =>
          {
              sort.Add(request => request.ID).Descending();
          })
          .PageSize(10)
          .Read(read => read.Action("GetCustomerHistory", "DataSource")))
          .Events(e => e.DataBound("OnHistoryDataBound"))
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I made the left/right edges of the div that's wrapping the Kendo Grid to overflow. By doing this, I'm able to keep the grid inside the screen and scroll through it to view the columns.

```
$("table").parent().css("overflow-x", "auto");
```